# Joining a calendar table to a sales table to get total sales for every day in a specified range

Tags: php, mysql

I have a 'sales' table called `phpbb_sold` which records each 'sale' as a row.
I am able to use a WHERE clause with the `uitemid` field to select one particular item in the sales records, as seen below:

```
SELECT uitemid, locktime, migrated_sold FROM phpbb_sold WHERE uitemid=342;

+---------+------------+---------------+
| uitemid |  locktime  | migrated_sold |
+---------+------------+---------------+
|     342 | 1632523854 |             1 |
|     342 | 1634239244 |             1 |
|     342 | 1634240072 |             1 |
|     342 | 1636367271 |             1 |
+---------+------------+---------------+
```

`uitemid` = number that identifies this as a sale of X item. `locktime` = UNIX timestamp that shows the datetime that the item was sold. `migrated_sold` = the quantity of the item sold. So this is nice, I have a table that keeps a record of each sale as it happens.

What I want to achieve though, is a record of the total number of sales of this item type, **for each day** in a 6 month period spanning back from the current date, and including each day **regardless of whether a sale was made or not**. So the desired output of my query would be:

```
SELECT (the query I want goes here) and returns the following rows...;

+------------+------------+
|  caldate   | sold_total |
+------------+------------+
| 2021-09-23 |          2 |
| 2021-09-24 |          0 |
| 2021-09-25 |          1 |
| 2021-09-26 |          0 |
| 2021-09-27 |          0 |
| 2021-09-28 |          1 |
+------------+------------+
```

Note that each day is included as a row in the results, even where the sales total for that day is `0`. I read that to do this, I would be required to create a calendar table with one column and all the days I want as rows, so I went ahead and did that:

```
SELECT caldate FROM phpbb_calendar;

+------------+
|  caldate   |
+------------+
| 2021-09-23 |
| 2021-09-24 |
| 2021-09-25 |
| 2021-09-26 |
| 2021-09-27 |
| 2021-09-28 |
+------------+
```

Now all that remains is for me to make the query. I need to somehow return all the rows from the `phpbb_calendar` table, joining the data from `sum()` (?) of the total `migrated_sold` for those days where exists, and a 0 where no sales took place.

I anticipated some issues with the UNIX timestamp, but it's okay because I am able to get `caldate` and `locktime` fields to be the same format by using `from_unixtime(locktime, '%Y-%m-%d')`, so both dates will be in the `YYYY-MM-DD` format for comparison.

Please could someone help me with this. I've gotten so close every time but it seems that everyone else's request is only slightly different from mine, so existing questions and answers have not been able to satisfy my requirements.

End goal is to use a JS chart library (AnyChart) to show a line graph of the number of sales of the item over time. But to get there, I first need to provide it with the query necessary for it to display that data.

Thanks

## Update

Using this query:

```
SELECT c.caldate, u.uitemid, sum(v.migrated_sold) as total_sales
from phpbb_calendar c cross join
     (select distinct uitemid from phpbb_sold) u left join
     phpbb_sold v
     on c.caldate = from_unixtime(v.locktime, '%Y-%m-%d') WHERE u.uitemid = 39 and c.caldate <= curdate() GROUP BY c.caldate ORDER BY c.caldate;
```

Returns:

[image]

But as you can see, it's just tallying up the total number of sales ever made or something - its clearly incrementing in a way I don't understand.
I don't want it to do that - I want it to count the number of total sales **on each day individually**. The results should look like this:

[image]

So that what is returned is basically a 'histogram' of sales, if any occurred, including 'empty' days where there were no sales (so these empty days must still be returned as rows).

Comment: What version of MySQL?

Comment: Hi Gerard, MySQL version is 5.7.29-log

Comment: If you would be so kind as to create a DBFiddle with your tables and some data.

Comment: @GerardH.Pille I have made a DBFiddle here: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/qY3zAnB57NMsgZSCEfV4JJ/3

It has one thousand data points in the phpbb_sold table, using three different item 'types' (represented by integer in the 'uitemid' field). The field 'topic_id' is the unique identifier for each sale, 'locktime' is the UNIX timestamp of when the sale was made, and finally 'migrated_sold' is the quantity sold.

Comment: Does phpbb_calendar.caldate give you a contiguous date range for the last 6 months in unix_timestamps?

Comment: @nnichols no, phpbb_calendar.caldate is in string format 'YYYY-MM-DD', because I am trying to target the individual days as opposed to the exact datetime offered by the unix timestamps. So it has those dates as strings starting from 23rd September 2021 (2021-09-23) and going all the way 5 years into the future.

Comment: Do you want to do it for all dates and uitemids in one go, as your cross join suggests, or with where clause for uitemid? Do you have a table to query for the items or is the DISTINCT uitemid the only option?

Comment: @nnichols I'd like to have the option to keep the where clause for the uitemid, so that I can query different product types using that in the future. I want to do it for all dates up till the current date.

Re: table to query for the items - well each sale has a unique identifier (topic_id), and also has a 'type' identifier (uitemid) as you can see in the fiddle, so you could grab either with a query, yes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```sql
SELECT c.caldate, u.uitemid, COALESCE(SUM(v.migrated_sold), 0) AS total_sales
FROM phpbb_calendar c
CROSS JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT uitemid FROM phpbb_sold WHERE uitemid = 37) u
LEFT JOIN phpbb_sold v
    ON v.locktime BETWEEN UNIX_TIMESTAMP(TIMESTAMP(c.caldate)) AND UNIX_TIMESTAMP(TIMESTAMP(c.caldate, '23:59:59'))
    AND u.uitemid = v.uitemid
WHERE c.caldate BETWEEN CURDATE() - INTERVAL 6 MONTH AND CURDATE()
GROUP BY c.caldate, u.uitemid
ORDER BY c.caldate;
```

N.B. I have changed your join to use the unix_timestamp as it should be more efficient and it can use any existing index on `locktime`

Comment: Thanks nnichols, I used uitemid 37 as a test (seeing as it's in this schema) and got it to return what I needed! https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/f4QB8D1zythFGxkS86jZ3v/0

The last hurdle I suppose is to return the number '0' instead of 'null' for those null values, so that my graphing solution can interpret those null values as zeroes on the graph.

Comment: Added coalesce around the sum. I also moved the criterion for uitemid to the sub-query.

Answer (score 0):

check this out:

```
select id, d, sum(s) from (
select U.id, d, 0 s from (
 select adddate(current_date(),-rows.r)  d from (
  select (@row_number := @row_number + 1) r
   from information_schema.columns,
        (SELECT @row_number := 0) AS x
   limit 200
 ) rows
) dates,
(SELECT distinct uitemid id FROM `phpbb_sold`) U
where d > adddate(current_date(), interval -6 month)
union
select uitemid, date(from_unixtime(locktime)),sum(migrated_sold)
  from `phpbb_sold`
  group by uitemid, date(from_unixtime(locktime))
) sales_union
group by id, d
order by id, d;
```

see [dbfiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/qY3zAnB57NMsgZSCEfV4JJ/4)
no need for calendar table

Comment: Nearly there Gerard!

Let's say I just want to see the sales history of uitemid 37 now using a WHERE clause, and ordering it by date (like a histogram) as opposed to by uitemid? Thanks

Comment: The "d" is the date, and ordered, if you didn't notice.  One possibility would be to replace "SELECT distinct uitemid id FROM `phpbb_sold`" by "SELECT 37" and add a where-clause before "group by uitemid, date(from_unixtime(locktime))".

Comment: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/qY3zAnB57NMsgZSCEfV4JJ/6

Comment: Thanks Gerard, that's working very well.

Comment: Do you understand the select from information_schema.columns?